# what is facebook SMTP server and port?

Tags: facebook, smtp

I would like to know facebook SMTP server and port. In postmaster, what see is only outbond.

http://postmaster.facebook.com/outbound

I tried with SMTP.facebook.com, it doesn't work at all. please let me know if you know about facebook smtp and port.

Comment: From [Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_vs_mail_retrieval)
> SMTP is a delivery protocol only. It cannot pull messages from a remote server on demand. Other protocols, such as the Post Office Protocol (POP) and the Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) are specifically designed for retrieving messages and managing mail boxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`smtpout.mx.facebook.com Port 25`

You can check using headers:

`Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO smtpout.mx.facebook.com) (66.220.157.69)
  by mta1019.mail.mud.yahoo.com with SMTP; Wed, 24 Aug 2011 09:41:46 -0700`

Comment: you are right, now i need to find out how to send with SMTP, when I tried to send out with, i am getting POL-P7 of facebook. "The message does not comply with Facebook's Domain Authentication requirements".

Comment: You shouldn't be sending e-mail through Facebook's outbound SMTP server. It's up to you to have your own SMTP server, which will contact recipient server. What are you trying to do, OP?

Comment: Instead of using my own smtp server, I would like to send it through. When I test with Rolosoft EMail Checker. It came out good. 
[2011-08-25T09:25:09]<Rolosoft Email Checker. Validation session log:>
[2011-08-25T09:25:08]<Init> 220 smtpin.mx.facebook.com ESMTP
[2011-08-25T09:25:08]<Helo> 250 smtpin.mx.facebook.com says HELO to 64.38.10.178:60054
[2011-08-25T09:25:09]<MailFrom> 250 MAIL FROM accepted
[2011-08-25T09:25:09]<RcptTo> 250 RCPT TO accepted
[2011-08-25T09:25:09]<Quit> 221 smtpin.mx.facebook.com closing connection
So I think, that one is not outbound SMTP server at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to send email as facebook? I believe this is only possible through the api, which will send the email for you.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.sendEmail/

Comment: I read this posted of "As of Mar. 1, the API will stop working and everyone are left alone to figure out your own email solution. This goes for regular notifications, both user to user and app to user, as well." on other topic. So it seems it is not working for API developers. I am just asking for their SMTP server to communicate without API.

Comment: It looks like they are depreciating it in the REST api, and adding it to the Graph api. In any case, you will need you own smtp server if you want to send email from your program without using the api.

Answer (score 0):

It's very rare (and usually an accident) for a company to allow third parties besides registered users to use its SMTP server.

If your goal is to send email to users, your best option is requesting the "email" permission from users when they log in.  Using the Javascript SDK this would be:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // callback function body here
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

You should then be able to see the user's `email` field when making a Graph API call, and can use your own mailer to send to them.